# Double series of Harmonic Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, zeta-functions, harmonic-numbers, polygamma

In a solution presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949776/closed-form-of-int-01-ln1-x-ln1x-lnx2-dx/951497#951497) a series involving the product of Harmonic numbers is involved. The intent of the problem is to determine a form of the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+1) (n+s+3)^{3}}
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} H_{k}}{k+1} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n}}{(n+1) (n+s+3)^{3}} \right)
\end{align}
has a closed form. Alternatively, one could calculate the series
\begin{align}
A_{n} = \sum_{s=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{s-1} \, H_{n-s} H_{s} }{ (s+1)(n-s+1) }
\end{align}
and then find a closed form of the series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{A_{n}}{(n+3)^{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have obtained a closed form using Mathematica after some preparatory steps.

**EDIT: simplification of problem and solution**

Consider the more general sum

$$g(p,s) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{(n+1) (n+s+3)^p}\tag{E1} $$

In the OP we had $p=3$.

The sum converges for $p \gt 0$ and, trivially, for an $s$ such that a pole due to summing is avoided.

Now we notice that higher values of $p$ can be generated by differentiating with respect to $s$. Namely

$$g(p+1,s) = -\frac{1}{p} \frac{\partial g(p,s)}{\partial s}\tag{E2}$$

But, luckily, for $p=1$ Mathematica yields immediately the closed expression

$$g(1,s) = \frac{1}{{2 s+4}}(\psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2+2 \gamma  \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)-\psi ^{(1)}(s+3)+\gamma ^2+\frac{\pi ^2}{6})\tag{E3}$$

Using (E3) and (E2) we can generate the closed expressions for a whole family of sums (E1).

**Original post**

First of all we define the sum to be calculated

$$f_s(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{(n+1) (n+s+3)^3}\tag{1}$$

Then we generate part of the denominator writing

$$\frac{1}{(n+s+3)^3}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} t^2 \exp (t (-(n+s+3))) \, dt\tag{2}$$

Inserting this in (1) and observing

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n x^n}{n+1}= \frac{\log ^2(1-x)}{2 x}\tag{3}$$

we get

$$f_i(s)=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{\infty } t^2 e^{-(s+2) t} \log ^2\left(1-e^{-t}\right) \, dt\tag{4}$$

This integral is evaluated by Mathematica to give the lengthy expression

$$f_\psi(s)\tag{5} = \frac{1}{24 (s+2)^4}\left(\left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) (s+2)+6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^4+12 \gamma  (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^3-12 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2) \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^3+6 \gamma ^2 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2+\pi ^2 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2+6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2-24 \gamma  (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2) \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2+6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(1)}(s+2) \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2-36 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(1)}(s+3) \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)^2+12 \gamma  (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2 \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)+36 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2) \psi ^{(1)}(s+3) \psi ^{(0)}(s+3)+6 \gamma ^2 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2+\pi ^2 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2-2 \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2-6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(1)}(s+2)^2+18 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(1)}(s+3)^2+2 (s+2) \left(6 \gamma -\left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) (s+2)\right) \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)+6 (s+2) (1-4 \gamma  (s+2)) \psi ^{(1)}(s+2)-6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2)^2 \psi ^{(1)}(s+3)+12 (s+2)^2 (\gamma  (s+2)+2) \psi ^{(2)}(s+3)+12 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(0)}(s+2) \psi ^{(2)}(s+3)-6 (s+2)^3 \psi ^{(3)}(s+3)+36 \gamma \right)$$

Here $\gamma$ is Euler's constant and $\psi ^{(k)}(s)$ is the polygamma function which can be expressed in terms of the harmonic number.

As a numerical check we take values at $s=1.2$

$$N(f_s(1.2) = 0.00949182, N(f_\psi(1.2)) = 0.00949182$$

For some non positive integer values of $s$ we have in the format $\{s, f(s), N(f(s))\}$

$$
\begin{array}{c}
 \left\{0,\frac{\psi ^{(2)}(3)}{2}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}+\frac{15}{8}-\frac{\pi ^4}{720},0.0177186\right\} \\
 \left\{-1,\psi ^{(2)}(2)-\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-\frac{\pi ^4}{360}+4,0.0354373\right\} \\
 \left\{-2,\frac{1}{12} \left(\pi ^2 \psi ^{(2)}(1)-\psi ^{(4)}(1)\right),0.0965512\right\} \\
 \left\{-3,\frac{1}{72} \left(342 \psi ^{(2)}(1)+\pi ^4+12 \pi ^2-270 \psi ^{(2)}(2)+540\right),0.593724\right\} \\
\end{array}
\tag{6}$$

For negative integer values $s\le -4$ the function $f(s)$ has triple poles with residues $H_k/(k+1)$ where $k=-s-3$.

The asymptotic behaviour is given by

$$f(s\to \infty) \sim \frac{1}{2 s^3}(\log(s)^2+2 \gamma  \log(s)-3 \log(s) +\zeta (2)+\gamma ^2-3 \gamma +1)\tag{7}$$

In order to avoid typing errors in further use here is the complete Mathematica expression of $f(s)$

```
f[s_] = 1/(24 (2 + 
     s)^4) (36 EulerGamma + (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2) (2 + s) + 
    2 (2 + s) (6 EulerGamma - (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2) (2 + 
          s)) PolyGamma[0, 2 + s] + 
    6 EulerGamma^2 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 
      2 + s]^2 + \[Pi]^2 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s]^2 - 
    2 (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2) (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s]^2 + 
    12 EulerGamma (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s]^2 PolyGamma[0, 
      3 + s] + 
    6 EulerGamma^2 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 
      3 + s]^2 + \[Pi]^2 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^2 - 
    24 EulerGamma (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s] PolyGamma[0, 
      3 + s]^2 + 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s]^2 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^2 + 
    12 EulerGamma (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^3 - 
    12 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s] PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^3 + 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^4 + 
    6 (2 + s) (1 - 4 EulerGamma (2 + s)) PolyGamma[1, 2 + s] + 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^2 PolyGamma[1, 2 + s] - 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[1, 2 + s]^2 - 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s]^2 PolyGamma[1, 3 + s] + 
    36 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s] PolyGamma[0, 3 + s] PolyGamma[1, 
      3 + s] - 
    36 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 3 + s]^2 PolyGamma[1, 3 + s] + 
    18 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[1, 3 + s]^2 + 
    12 (2 + s)^2 (2 + EulerGamma (2 + s)) PolyGamma[2, 3 + s] + 
    12 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[0, 2 + s] PolyGamma[2, 3 + s] - 
    6 (2 + s)^3 PolyGamma[3, 3 + s]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reputation roints. After rereading the OP carefully I noticed that I have not solved the problem (which iis quadratic in $H_n$) but another Problem which is linear in $H_n$. Sorry. Hopefully, I have at least contributed a little to the solution of the intended problem.